# How to add n number of rows in TableLayout at at runtime in android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I just need your help. I want to develop an application which includes TableLayout and also i want to add n number of rows at run time. i have tried searching many stuffs, could'nt find the possible way. So anyone can help or provide any reference.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int count=20
    TableLayout tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout); //table layout in xml
                              for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
                              {

                                  TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                                  tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                  TextView textview = new TextView(this);
                                  textview.setText("hello");
                                  tr.addView(textview);


                                  tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            }



     }
```

Thanks